# Ramanujan Identity Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, q-series, elliptic-modular-form

Ramanujan defined a now famous q-series as

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^2} = \left(-q;q^2\right)^2_{\infty}\left(q^2;q^2\right)_{\infty}$$

I wanted to prove this identity but I wasn't sure where to begin. I tried looking for an identity involving
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{k}$$
for $k=n^2$ however it doesn't seem to converge and so I was stuck at this. I also attempted to work backwards starting with a decomposition of $\left(-q;q^2\right)^2_{\infty}\left(q^2;q^2\right)_{\infty}$ but that also quickly led nowhere. Does anyone know how to prove this?

Comment: This is a special case ($x=1$) of the famous Jacobi Triple product identity $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} x^nq^{n^2}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2n})(1+xq^{2n-1})(1+x^{-1}q^{2n-1})$ which holds for all $x\neq 0$ and $|q|<1$.

Comment: For a proof by Jacobi see http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-theta-functions-contd.html?m=0